# Copying Within Samba Share Downloads Locally

Tags: network-shares, samba, kubuntu, dolphin-file-manager

I'm have a headless nas server running a Samba share, and I'm trying to copy files from one folder on the share, to another folder on the same share. Terminal commands are a bit cumbersome, and its much easier to just highlight all the folders I want. The problem I'm having is the move and copy functions are downloading to my pc (Kubuntu 16.04) first, and then copying back to the share. This doesnt seem to happen on Windows clients, and considering I'm wanting to move in the region of 10G-100G of files at a time, it would be handier to not have the overhead. I'm using Dolphin as my file explorer. I've tried both accessing from the smb://server/share path and mounting them in my filesystem as well. Happens regardless. Server runs Arch if thats relevant